Problem with model constraints in ANSYS mechanical
I've been trying to run an analysis of the geometry in the attached images. The geometry consists of an inner tube with protrusions along an axis (this axis is not parallel to the Y axis) and an outer tube. It is similar to a double-bonded rubber bush if there was no rubber in between the inner and outer tube.
I'm trying to analyse an application where force is applied on the outer tube through the housing it's sitting in, bringing it in contact with the inner tube, which sits on a shaft (assumed non-deformable).
My set-up is as follows:

Frictional contact with a pinball region of radius 0.2mm between the inner surface of the outer tube and the outer surfaces of the protrusion on the inner tube - Image 2

Fixed support on the inner surface of the ring - Image 3

Remote displacement on the outer surface of the outer tube with all rotational displacements and translation along X and Z constrained to 0 - Image 4

Force on the outer surface of the outer tube -Image 5


I have tried a few other things as well, but it won't solve. I've been getting the following error: "An internal solution magnitude limit was exceeded. Please check your Environment for inappropriate load values or insufficient supports". I understand this is usually as a result of insufficient constraints, but for the life of me, I can't figure out why it's insufficiently constrained.
Please help!!





Could you use displacement instead of the force on top? This way, the outer tube should be fully constrained and you can get the force at various displacements from reaction.
